# How to achieve the below layout with help of CSS for a responsive web page?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve the following layout for one of the pages I am building using bootstrap 4.

[image: Layout]

Sections 1 and 2 are basically container fluids with col-4/col-8 and col-5/col-7 layouts and have a background image or background color.

On top of this I have to place a div with some text and button, and depending on the placement, left or right column, the content must be confined to the size of container i.e. left and right margins same as set by container. This also needs to be responsive in nature.

I have tried adding margins based on media queries that seems to be a very ugly solution.

**How do I achieve this in a more efficient way?**

*Thanks!!*

Comment: Please put your code here with your css so we can help!

Comment: This is what I have done:

Comment: Where is it? :)